# PUT upload php curl command response is "Missing Content-Length header."

Tags: php, rest, curl, upload, put

I write a php script to upload a media file but when I use it the response occurs:

> Missing Content-Length header.

The php code is:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://raz-ul.domenka.com/v1/AUTH_8a619275-f933-4da1-b289-0ca1a2a3a4a5/bcd/drop1.avi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkd78bedda5bec4613b80becb1b2b3b4b5";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$header_size  = $info['header_size'];
$header       = substr($response, 0, $header_size);

var_dump($header);
```

On the other hand When I do something like that in cli I succeed:

```
kinduser@43915-1-c1c2c3-01:~/public_html/adam$ curl -i -X PUT -H "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkd78bedda5bec4613b80bec0123456789" -T drop.avi https://raz-ul.domenka.com/v1/AUTH_8a619275-f933-4da1-b289-0ca1a2a3a4a5/bcd/drop.avi
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Last-Modified: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 10:12:54 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Etag: fa60ba1b78299bfae5ac61d1d2d3d4d5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Trans-Id: tx114b22027223415c850db-e1e2e3e4e5
Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2017 10:12:53 GMT

kinduser@43915-1-c1c2c3-01:~/public_html/adam$
```

But I would like to do this in php. How to fix my php code?

**Update**
I added some code to tell curl which file to send. It sent the file but the file changed on the server. It got a bigger weight from 660kB to 660.31kB. After downloading to my pc it got impossible to open via video player.

That code is like this now:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://raz-ul.domenka.com/v1/AUTH_8a619275-f933-4da1-b289-0ca1a2a3a4a5/bcd/drop7.avi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Auth-Token: AUTH_tkd78bedda5bec4613b80becb1b2b3b4b5";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$curlFile = curl_file_create ('./drop.avi');

$post = array (
    'extra_info' => '123456',
    'file_contents' => $curlFile
);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$header_size  = $info['header_size'];
$header       = substr($response, 0, $header_size);

var_dump($header);
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't provide any content to upload, so it actually has no length to send...